# How to redirect requests on IP to domain

Tags: nginx

Every once in a while someone is trying to access our website through the public ip instead of one of our domains (yes we have multiple country specific domains .dk, .it, .es etc. however we also have .com as the "general").

Now I would like to redirect those requests coming in on the IP-adress to our www.domain.com domain instead. How would I do that in nginx without touching anything BUT requests going directly to the IP?

Here is my nginx.conf

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.mysite.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;

  root /home/deployer/apps/mysite/current/public;
  proxy_set_header X-Request-Start "t=${msec}";
  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }
  error_page 503 @maintenance;
  location @maintenance {
    rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html last;
    break;
  }

  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

}
```

So the question would be, how do I modify this to redirect e.g. `http://123.123.123.123/some_page` to `http://www.mysite.com/some_page` but leave all other like `http://www.mysite.dk/some_page`unchanged?

Comment: Try changing `default` to `default_server` in your `listen` directive. Then add `server_name _;` below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup a catchall server with the following directives:

```
listen 80 default_server;
server_name _;
```

If you have multiple server stanzas, you can use `default_server` to specify the configuration that is used if the hostname doesn't match any of the other `server_name` entries. Using an ip number fits this scenario. The `server_name _;` line acts as a null `server_name` entry.

It's also useful if one of your servers has multiple domain names.

Comment: Don't understand, could you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: @Niels, I've added an explanation to my answer. Does it help?

Comment: Hmm I think I need to read up on nginx configurations in order to understand how this works. I have added my nginx config so you can see it - and maybe help inline.